# Linux iptables DNAT stops working after some time

Tags: linux, iptables, nat

I have a strange behaviour in my server setup. It looks like that.

client1 192.168.11.2/24 <----> 192.168.11.7/24 (br1/vlan1) Server 192.168.21.1/24 (br21/vlan21) <---> 192.168.21.101/24 client2

On the server I have set up DNAT for two ports to another destination.

```
~> sudo iptables -t nat  -nL -v 
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 3631 packets, 220K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
 5332  320K DNAT       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.11.7         multiport dports 5308,21 to:192.168.2.19

~> ip r get 192.168.2.19
192.168.2.19 via 192.168.11.1 dev br1  src 192.168.11.7
```

This works for some time from both clients but after an unspecified time only packets from client2 are forwarded any more. The packet counter increases when I try to connect from client1 but there is no NAT any more. Sometimes it started to work again after some hours.

Nothing is blocked in the firewall because all policies are on ACCEPT and no rules where set. The conntrack is not full either. I already tried multiple things with rp_filter and so on but this should be no problem in these setup.

Hopefully someone has an idea.

Comment: It's OpenSuse 13.1 x86_64 kernel 3.11.10-7-default.

Comment: I suspect `multiport` might do some harm to you.  How about expanding it into multiple ordinary rules and watch the stability of the system?

Comment: I already did that but it doesn't change anything. So I reverted to the old rule.

Comment: Strange. You might get better help on serverfault.com though. I'll respectfully close and suggest transfer there, OK?

Comment: I just found out something. When I start a tcpdump looking on br1 on tcp port 21 the the connection works fine as long as the dump runs.

OK, I will switch to serverfault.com.

Comment: So setting the interface br1 to promiscuous mode with "ifconfig br1 promisc" fixes the problem, but I would like to understand what happens.